# Erro "java.lang.AbstractMethodError" ao acessar projeto migrado do WebServer GlassFish para o Payara

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, glassfish, ejb

Migrei um projeto que estava no WebService GlassFish, para o Payara. A implantação ocorreu sem nenhum tipo de erro. Mas quando acesso o projeto, ele acusa um erro: `java.lang.AbstractMethodError`. Não realizei nenhuma modificação no projeto para que o erro surgisse. Apenas fiz a troca do servidor.

Segue o erro que consta no Log, abaixo:

```
    [2023-03-24T13:24:53.881-0300] [Payara 5.2020.3] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=74 _ThreadName=http-thread-pool::http-listener-2(4)] [timeMillis: 1679675093881] [levelValue: 900] [[

  StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception

java.lang.AbstractMethodError

    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatefulSessionContainer.createExtendedEMs(StatefulSessionContainer.java:781)

    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatefulSessionContainer.createBeanInstance(StatefulSessionContainer.java:712)

    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatefulSessionContainer.createEJBLocalBusinessObjectImpl(StatefulSessionContainer.java:660)

    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.createEJBLocalBusinessObjectImpl(BaseContainer.java:2533)

    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalHomeImpl.createEJBLocalBusinessObjectImpl(EJBLocalHomeImpl.java:117)

    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalHomeInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalHomeInvocationHandler.java:166)

    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1872.create(Unknown Source)

    at com.sun.ejb.EJBUtils.resolveEjbRefObject(EJBUtils.java:372)

    at com.sun.ejb.EjbNamingReferenceManagerImpl.resolveEjbReference(EjbNamingReferenceManagerImpl.java:197)

    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.ComponentEnvManagerImpl$EjbReferenceProxy.create(ComponentEnvManagerImpl.java:1015)

    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.lookup(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:770)

    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.lookup(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:738)

    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.JavaURLContext.lookup(JavaURLContext.java:159)

    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:476)

    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:442)

    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)

    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl._inject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:561)

    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.inject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:439)

    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.injectInstance(InjectionManagerImpl.java:153)

    at org.glassfish.faces.integration.GlassFishInjectionProvider.inject(GlassFishInjectionProvider.java:200)

    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.injectResources(BeanBuilder.java:179)

    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:77)

    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:387)

    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:247)

    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:200)

    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:55)

    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:156)

    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:184)

    at com.sun.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:91)

    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getBase(AstValue.java:125)

    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:173)

    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:183)

    at org.jboss.weld.module.web.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)

    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:73)

    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:170)

    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:157)

    at javax.faces.component.UIData.getValue(UIData.java:736)

    at javax.faces.component.UIData.getDataModel(UIData.java:1849)

    at javax.faces.component.UIData.setRowIndexWithoutRowStatePreserved(UIData.java:479)

    at javax.faces.component.UIData.setRowIndex(UIData.java:468)

    at javax.faces.component.UIData.visitTree(UIData.java:1441)

    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1468)

    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1468)

    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:347)

    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1468)

    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1468)

    at br.com.santa.view.handler.SecurityViewHandler.renderView(SecurityViewHandler.java:146)

    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:102)

    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:76)

    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:199)

    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.executeLifecyle(FacesServlet.java:708)

    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:451)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1636)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:331)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:211)

    at br.com.santa.filter.NoWebCache.doFilter(NoWebCache.java:64)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:253)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:211)

    at br.com.santa.filter.AjaxEncoding.doFilter(AjaxEncoding.java:59)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:253)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:211)

    at br.com.santa.filter.InternetExplorer8.doFilter(InternetExplorer8.java:60)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:253)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:211)

    at org.idc.upload.UploadFilter.doFilter(UploadFilter.java:68)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:253)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:211)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:257)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:757)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:577)

    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:158)

    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:371)

    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:238)

    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:520)

    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:217)

    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler$1.run(HttpHandler.java:200)

    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:569)

    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:549)

    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

]]



[2023-03-24T13:24:53.881-0300] [Payara 5.2020.3] [SEVERE] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=74 _ThreadName=http-thread-pool::http-listener-2(4)] [timeMillis: 1679675093881] [levelValue: 1000] [[

  javax.servlet.ServletException: Um erro ocorreu ao realizar a inje��o de recurso no bean gerenciado pesquisaBean

    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.executeLifecyle(FacesServlet.java:725)

    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:451)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1636)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:331)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:211)

    at br.com.santa.filter.NoWebCache.doFilter(NoWebCache.java:64)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:253)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:211)

    at br.com.santa.filter.AjaxEncoding.doFilter(AjaxEncoding.java:59)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:253)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:211)

    at br.com.santa.filter.InternetExplorer8.doFilter(InternetExplorer8.java:60)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:253)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:211)

    at org.idc.upload.UploadFilter.doFilter(UploadFilter.java:68)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:253)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:211)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:257)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:757)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:577)

    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:158)

    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:371)

    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:238)

    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:520)

    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:217)

    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler$1.run(HttpHandler.java:200)

    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:569)

    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:549)

    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Caused by: com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException: Um erro ocorreu ao realizar a inje��o de recurso no bean gerenciado pesquisaBean

    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.injectResources(BeanBuilder.java:185)

    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:77)

    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:387)

    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:247)

    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:200)

    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:55)

    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:156)

    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:184)

    at com.sun.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:91)

    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getBase(AstValue.java:125)

    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:173)

    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:183)

    at org.jboss.weld.module.web.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)

    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:73)

    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:170)

    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:157)

    at javax.faces.component.UIData.getValue(UIData.java:736)

    at javax.faces.component.UIData.getDataModel(UIData.java:1849)

    at javax.faces.component.UIData.setRowIndexWithoutRowStatePreserved(UIData.java:479)

    at javax.faces.component.UIData.setRowIndex(UIData.java:468)

    at javax.faces.component.UIData.visitTree(UIData.java:1441)

    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1468)

    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1468)

    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:347)

    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1468)

    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1468)

    at br.com.santa.view.handler.SecurityViewHandler.renderView(SecurityViewHandler.java:146)

    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:102)

    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:76)

    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:199)

    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.executeLifecyle(FacesServlet.java:708)

    ... 30 more

Caused by: com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderException: com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Exception attempting to inject Local ejb-ref name=br.com.santa.controller.PesquisaBean/projetoFacade,Local 3.x interface =br.com.santa.dao.IProjetoFacade resolved to intra-app EJB ProjetoFacade in module ft,ejb-link=ProjetoFacade,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=,refType=Session into class br.com.santa.controller.PesquisaBean: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/env/br.com.santa.controller.PesquisaBean/projetoFacade' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming}

    at org.glassfish.faces.integration.GlassFishInjectionProvider.inject(GlassFishInjectionProvider.java:208)

    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.injectResources(BeanBuilder.java:179)

    ... 60 more

Caused by: com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Exception attempting to inject Local ejb-ref name=br.com.santa.controller.PesquisaBean/projetoFacade,Local 3.x interface =br.com.santa.dao.IProjetoFacade resolved to intra-app EJB ProjetoFacade in module ft,ejb-link=ProjetoFacade,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=,refType=Session into class br.com.santa.controller.PesquisaBean: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/env/br.com.santa.controller.PesquisaBean/projetoFacade' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming}

    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl._inject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:638)

    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.inject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:439)

    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.injectInstance(InjectionManagerImpl.java:153)

    at org.glassfish.faces.integration.GlassFishInjectionProvider.inject(GlassFishInjectionProvider.java:200)

    ... 61 more

Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/env/br.com.santa.controller.PesquisaBean/projetoFacade' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: No object bound for java:comp/env/br.com.santa.controller.PesquisaBean/projetoFacade [Root exception is javax.ejb.EJBException: Couldn't create EntityManager for refName: br.com.santa.dao.ProjetoFacade/em; unitname: fichaPU]]

    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:496)

    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:442)

    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)

    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl._inject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:561)

    ... 64 more

Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: No object bound for java:comp/env/br.com.santa.controller.PesquisaBean/projetoFacade [Root exception is javax.ejb.EJBException: Couldn't create EntityManager for refName: br.com.santa.dao.ProjetoFacade/em; unitname: fichaPU]

    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.JavaURLContext.lookup(JavaURLContext.java:229)

    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:476)

    ... 67 more

Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException: Couldn't create EntityManager for refName: br.com.santa.dao.ProjetoFacade/em; unitname: fichaPU

    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatefulSessionContainer.createExtendedEMs(StatefulSessionContainer.java:786)

    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatefulSessionContainer.createBeanInstance(StatefulSessionContainer.java:712)

    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatefulSessionContainer.createEJBLocalBusinessObjectImpl(StatefulSessionContainer.java:660)

    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.createEJBLocalBusinessObjectImpl(BaseContainer.java:2533)

    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalHomeImpl.createEJBLocalBusinessObjectImpl(EJBLocalHomeImpl.java:117)

    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalHomeInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalHomeInvocationHandler.java:166)

    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1872.create(Unknown Source)

    at com.sun.ejb.EJBUtils.resolveEjbRefObject(EJBUtils.java:372)

    at com.sun.ejb.EjbNamingReferenceManagerImpl.resolveEjbReference(EjbNamingReferenceManagerImpl.java:197)

    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.ComponentEnvManagerImpl$EjbReferenceProxy.create(ComponentEnvManagerImpl.java:1015)

    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.lookup(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:770)

    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.lookup(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:738)

    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.JavaURLContext.lookup(JavaURLContext.java:159)

    ... 68 more

Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError

    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatefulSessionContainer.createExtendedEMs(StatefulSessionContainer.java:781)

    ... 80 more

]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Vou escrever uma resposta porque ainda não tenho reputação suficiente para escrever comentários.

Olhando apenas o log de erro, sem o código das classes que são citadas, é bem difícil dizer com precisão seu problema.

De acordo com o log, eu diria que você tem um EJB `br.com.santa.controller.PesquisaBean` que injeta um DAO `br.com.santa.dao.ProjetoFacade` que, por sua vez, injeta o `javax.persistence.EntityManager`. Aparentemente, quando o container foi tentar criar uma instância para o `EntityManager`, algo deu errado. Além disso, o log faz referência ao nome da *Persistence Unit* `fichaPU`.

A troca de um servidor de aplicação - Glassfish por Payara, no seu caso, na maioria das vezes, não é tão simples assim.

Um exemplo clássico de um ponto onde ocorrem problemas são as definições de *DataSources*. Sua aplicação provavelmente referência um `DataSource` por seu nome `JNDI` no arquivo `persistence.xml`, mas esse *DataSource* foi definido no Payara antes?

Outro ponto que pode gerar problema são as versões de diferentes servidores de aplicação. Qual a versão do Glassfish que você está usando? Qual a versão da especificação Jakarta EE - no seu caso parece ser Java EE ainda - que sua aplicação usa? Diferentes servidores de aplicação suportam diferentes versões do Java EE / Jakarta EE.